# How to use NSWorkspace to be able to open a filetype? - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsworkspace

My app is able to extract .deb files but only if you specify where with buttons in the app. But I want to be able to just click on a .deb file and have my app open up, run the actions I already have, then quit when it's done. Right now I'm using NSWorspace to tell my app it can open .deb files but I don't know how to have it run my actions from that. Is using NSWorkspace even the right thing to do? I also need to be able to get the Filepath of the file being opened in string format and I can't seem to fighure this out?

Comment: You might want to consider making a [document based application](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Documents.html), which would provide the abilities you want while still letting you open a file with a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing and this might be of interest to others, too. Solution is lined out by a little example.

Create a new Cocoa project in Xcode, go to the xib and add a label to the window. We will use it for a proof of concept. Next, some stuff to your app delegate. Interface:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface fileClickerAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
NSWindow *window;
NSTextField *fileName;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *fileName;

@end
```

The implementation is pretty straight forward:

```
#import "fileClickerAppDelegate.h"

@implementation fileClickerAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize fileName;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

}

- (void)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames {

    [fileName setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wow, even multiple files like %d :-)", [filenames count]]];
}

@end
```

There is one method to keep an eye on:

application:openFiles.

Guess what it does? It receives a list of files passed from either having clicked on an item on the desktop or in the finder, or having dragged files onto the icon. It will be passed an array with the filenames, along with the paths, UNIX style.

My tests did not require to set "Document types" in the plist of the app, or doing fancy registration stuff with the finder. Of course, this could add...

That should fix your problem and you can do whatever you want with your .deb files (I assume debian packages?).

Good luck!

Living

P.S.: Just do not forget to hook up the NSTextField to the GUI control ;-) Otherwise, it will work but nothing is displayed....

Comment: Thanks this is great! Exactly what I was looking for, and by .deb I do mean DEBIAN packages. But how does the app know I am opening this filetype?

Comment: Like the app doesn't show up in finder as an app that can open this filetype. I have to manually search for it and open it

Comment: What do you mean by "does not show up in the finder"? If you are referring to "open with...", you have to manually register the application type.
First, go to your plist and add a key "Document types", this will add an array with on item. Be careful to use the correct key! The array contains a key for document type name, the value should be deb. The handler rank can be left alone, for now (ref. to docs).

Comment: To make your app the default app for .deb files, right-click on a .deb (e. g. on your workspace) and choose "information". You can choose the default application for the file type, just make sure you  change it for all files of that type (via the respective button).

Answer (score 0):

Please supply a bit more information on what exectly are you doing and maybe why it does not work, e. g. crash dump, gdb output, etc.

It is hard to guess what might help if you don't tell us what i going on.

Comment: so basically i want my app to open a file when you click it on your desktop as if it was like a word document file and run an action i have made that extracts it

Comment: I dont have any code either, I just want to be able to click on my file type in finder and have it open in my app and run a certain action and then close